# C# Skip anything to next tag

Tags: c#, xml, skip

I have a log file in xml format like

```
<log> // skip this node
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <qbean logger="main-logger">
  </qbean>
</log>
<log> // go to this node
</log>
```

Now ReadToNextSibling("log") throw an exception an I need to skip content of first "log" tag and move to next "log" tag without throwing exception.
Is there a way?

Comment: This is not valid `xml` Can you post `Xml` and what you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, this is not valid xml, but problem is always between some of log tags, and I need to ignore these tags, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Your XML is invalid since the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` has to be before the root element. You can search for it and remove it if that fixes your problem. You can use `yourXml.Repalce("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "")`
2. You have to create a root element for your XML to be valid for parsing.

Then, you can use the `XmlDocument` class to parse the XML data that you have and skip anything you want. You would need something like this:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();

document.LoadXml(yourXml);

document.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1]
```